# How to control tests per hour execution in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

i have below scenarios 
HomePage -  to be executed 5 times in an hour
Check-In - to be executed 15 times in an hour
Check-out - to be executed 20 times in an hour

In visual studio load test we have an userpace model where in we can configure TestName and No of times to be executed in an hour. Do we have similar feature in JMeter.
Can you please let me know on how this can be done.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Timers and controllers in Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UltimateThreadGroup` which is contained in `Custom Thread Groups` plugin. You could split up scenarios to different `Thread Groups`

Answer (score 0):

1. Put these 3 groups of users under different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. Use [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer/) to limit the rate of requests per minute to the desired rate. Alternatively you can consider [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) (the latter one you will need to install via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/))